# Are void zombies controllable by the akata that created them, and by the summoner of the akata?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, summoning, zombies

Are void zombies controllable by the akata that created it?

More importantly, since [akatas](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/akata/) are a possible [Summon Monster II](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-monster/#2nd-level) creature, if I summon one, have it infect another creature, and then kill that other creature, will the new void zombie be loyal to me, the summoner, via the akata's control?

If so, will it still be loyal to me after the akata disappears?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a Void Zombie is an Akata Larva hiding out in some poor souls dead body, I doubt the Akata has much control over it, in the way that the control exerted by most animals over their young is to pick them up and put them down.
(Or the control a human has over a baby. :P)

Not to mention that the pre-built [Void Zombie](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/zombie/zombie-void/) doesn't actually have a language.

As for Void Zombies created by a summoned Akata, that is an excellent question.

We know that spells will [terminate when a summoned creatures duration expires](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Conjuration), but the bite 'disease' isn't a spell. I'd probably have to say that non-spell abilities follow the same rule.

Comment: Ive looked over the link you posted, but wasnt able to find the part about a summoned creature's spells terminate when its gone, could you point it out to me?

Comment: No probs! Under Subschools, Summoning: "When the spell that summoned a creature ends and the creature disappears, all the spells it has cast expire."

Answer (score 2):

The Void Zombie has no special attachment to the Akata that created it, though it likely possesses the 'helpful' or 'friendly' attitude relative to its parent in most settings.  Void Zombies, however, *are* classified as Undead, and so subject to the [Command Undead feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/command-undead-final/) (and similar abilities), allowing a caster so inclined to control them (and keep them after the summoning expires, which is a nice bonus!).

Furthermore, the default behavior of Zombies, according to the cursed item [Gravesoul Armor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/cursed-items/#TOC-Gravesoul-Armor), is to "mindlessly attack unassociated creatures near them".  It is possible that the GM would rule the summoner an 'associated creature' and exceedingly likely that the GM would rule the parental Akata, other Akata, other Void Zombies of the same brood, and other Void Zombies in general "associated creatures" and thus not subject to the Zombie's default 'kill everything else' targeting.